# How to handle/inflate more then one recycleview activity from an adapter class

Tags: java, android

It's quite hard to put My doubt in words but ill try, Hi there I am creating simple book app where user can learn different languages like java,c,c++, and I got and question mark here. my question is how can I control/Inflate more than one RecycleView activity from an adapter class or should I make different RecycleViewand and adapter system for every single language.

i.e I just want an app having multiple buttons with different languages where user can click on the button and learn programming concept listed there he can come back and click another button in order to learn another language as well

"I hope you got my point"

Comment: you can use different data in a single adapter if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You must use different data

Also you can use different layout for any item

in your model.class (model of data for recyclerView you can define a variable for Type of data

ex :

```
public String getType() {
    return Type;
}

public void setType(String Type) {
    this.Type= Type;
}
```

i use from this setter and getter

so in your addapter class insert below method

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return   ;
}
```

with this method you can pass any value you want and get it as int i in myViewHohder onCreateViewHolder method

```
public myViewHohder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {


    return ;
}
```

and you can with a (if) Condition  to decide for layout of item